# How to convert/replace Express Middleware logic for Azure?

Tags: azure, express, middleware

Migrating our existing Nodes API backend to Azure serverless Functions, we have custom Express middleware implementation, for example typical router-middleware-controller

Router:

```
const mdw = require("../middleware/mdw");
module.exports = app =>
{
    const controller = require("../controller/mycontroller");
    app.post("/getmyprofile",      mdw.ValidateSession,    controller.GetMyProfile);
};
```

mdw:

```
const decode = require("jwt-decode");
const objPS = require("../DataModel/PostgreSql");
async function ValidateSession(req, res, next)
{
  theToken = req.headers["authorization"].toString().split(' ')[1]; 
  vuniqueid = decode(theToken).sub;  //decode and extract an unique ID from Header
  var vsessionid = req.cookies.MySessionID;  // SessionID from cookie
  var params = {sid: vsessionid, uid: vuniqueid};  // to be sent to DB for further check
  objPS.GetSession(params, (bad, good) =>
  {
    if (bad) {res.status401).send();}
    else 
    {
      res.locals.GoodSession = {...};  // pass this new obj for controller.GetMyProfile above
      next();
    }
  }
});
```

According to [MS Shifting from Express.js to Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/shift-expressjs?tabs=javascript)

> Many middleware modules are no longer required in light of Azure Functions and Azure API Management capabilities.
> Ensure you can replicate or replace any logic handled by essential
> middleware before migrating endpoints.

Well, it offers no sample or guidelines on how to. So where can I find info on how to?